# 'textSelectionColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: flutter, dart, e-commerce

in flutter , I have defined my custom theme like this
the problem is 'textSelectionColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use TextSelectionThemeData.selectionColor instead.

```
Text(
          'Your Cat Is Empty',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Theme.of(context).textSelectionColor, fontSize: 36),
        )
```

This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre..
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its help to you. used `textSelectionTheme.selectionColor`

Refer **`TextSelectionTheme`** [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/text-selection-theme)

```
  Text(
      'Your Cat Is Empty',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Theme.of(context).textSelectionTheme.selectionColor,
        fontSize: 36,
      ),
    ),
```

Result screen-> [image]

Comment: @JohnBenedictSabando if your problem has been solved so tick or accept the answer